# EJB 2.1 throwing wrapped remote exception in cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, ejb-2.x

We're in the processing of moving a Weblogic 10.3.6 app to Weblogic 12.2.1.2. We have many EJB 2.1 beans that form part of the app.  We've hit a strange problem with some of these beans.

When we have 1 ejb call another and this bean throws a checked exception (e.g. `RuleException extends Exception`) this is thrown as a `RemoteException` (`RemoteEJBInvokeException`).  This only occurs if the app is running in a cluster.  If I deploy against a standalone jvm it works fine.

The general EJB pattern is a Facade pattern.  In the Facade bean we use a standard JNDI lookup to locate the Home and then run the create method to return the business interface/impl

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ReportManagementHome reportManagementHome = (ReportManagementHome) ctx.lookup("ReportManagement");
ReportManagement reportManagement = reportManagementHome.create();
```

`ReportManagement` bean runs the business logic and throws a RuleException.

This is an example method in the facade that calls the 2nd bean:

```
public String doTest() {
    String s = null;
    try
    {
      s = reportManagement.doValidate();
    }
    catch ( RuleException re )
    {
      rollBack();
    } catch (RemoteException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return s;
  }
```

Here is the `doValidate()` method in the 2nd bean:

```
public String doValidate( )
      throws RuleException, CustomException
  {

    int test = 1;

    if (test == 1)
    {
      throw new RuleException();
    }

    return "Hello";

  }
```

Although the `RuleException` is correctly reached and thrown, by the time the facade catches it it is a `RemoteException`.

This is an example list of the ejbs/interfaces:

```
ReportManagement
ReportManagementBean
ReportManagementFacade
ReportManagementFacadeBean
ReportManagementFacadeHome
ReportManagementFacadeLocal
ReportManagementFacadeLocalHome
ReportManagementHome
ReportManagementLocal
ReportManagementLocalHome
```

Here is the `ejb-jar.xml`

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <display-name>ReportManagementFacade</display-name>
      <ejb-name>ReportManagementFacade</ejb-name>
      <home>com.ejb.ReportManagementFacadeHome</home>
      <remote>com.ejb.ReportManagementFacade</remote>
      <local-home>com.ejb.ReportManagementFacadeLocalHome</local-home>
      <local>com.ejb.ReportManagementFacadeLocal</local>
      <ejb-class>com.ejb.ReportManagementFacadeBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
    <session>
      <display-name>ReportManagement</display-name>
      <ejb-name>ReportManagement</ejb-name>
      <home>com.ejb.ReportManagementHome</home>
      <remote>com.ejb.ReportManagement</remote>
      <local-home>com.ejb.ReportManagementLocalHome</local-home>
      <local>com.ejb.ReportManagementLocal</local>
      <ejb-class>com.ejb.ReportManagementBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
  <assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
      <method>
        <ejb-name>ReportManagementFacade</ejb-name>
        <method-name>*</method-name>
      </method>
      <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
    <container-transaction>
      <method>
        <ejb-name>ReportManagement</ejb-name>
        <method-name>*</method-name>
      </method>
      <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
  </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

Here is the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.2/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">
  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>ReportManagementFacade</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>Destin8.ejb.reportmanagement.ReportManagementFacade</jndi-name>
    <local-jndi-name>Destin8.ejb.reportmanagement.ReportManagementFacadeLocal</local-jndi-name>
    <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>ReportManagement</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>Destin8.ejb.reportmanagement.ReportManagement</jndi-name>
    <local-jndi-name>Destin8.ejb.reportmanagement.ReportManagementLocal</local-jndi-name>
    <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
  <weblogic-compatibility>
    <entity-always-uses-transaction>true</entity-always-uses-transaction>
  </weblogic-compatibility>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

And here is the StackTrace:

```
weblogic.rmi.RemoteEJBInvokeException: null; nested exception is: 
    com.exception.RuleException
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:27)
    at com.ejb.ReportManagement_tq6u66_EOImpl.doLUMValidate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ejb.ReportManagementFacadeBean.doLUM(ReportManagementFacadeBean.java:82)
    at com.ejb.ReportManagementFacade_sidvua_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:54)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:21)
    at com.ejb.ReportManagementFacade_sidvua_EOImpl.doLUM(Unknown Source)
    at com.ajf.Page1ManagedBean.refreshDate(Page1ManagedBean.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: com.exception.RuleException
    at com.ejb.ReportManagementBean.doLUMValidate(ReportManagementBean.java:92)
    at com.ejb.ReportManagement_tq6u66_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:54)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:21)
    ... 55 more
```

Any guidance in this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `RuleException` serializable?

Comment: `public class RuleException extends Exception implements Serializable` Exception extends Throwable which implements Serializable so it's definitely Serializable.  Also in my test class it has no extra properties.

Comment: @andyfinch we are also facing the same issue, can you please tell us how did you solve it?

Comment: @RameshKotha We have a bug outstanding with Oracle [Bug 25729346](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=25729346&parent=SrDetailText&sourceId=3-14343659231)

Comment: Thanks @andyfinch am unable view the the link, can you please post the content?

Comment: @RameshKotha.  It doesn't really add much more than what is described here.  However I believe you just need an Oracle Support sign in to view this.

Comment: @andyfinch we upgraded EJB to 3.0 from 2.1 and the issue got resolved.!

Comment: @RameshKotha I know.  However we have many legacy 2.1 ejbs not ready to be converted.  Converting also involves us changing the lookup code used so lots of code changes for us.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but we have only one EJB component  , upgraded it. Everything is working fine as of now. Thanks for your time.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in a patch by Oracle on my request.  The link for that patch is here [Patch Link](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?requestId=21337323&_afrLoop=260323723329901&patchId=25729346&languageId=0&platformId=2000&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=vvlvw7cab_111).  You will need an Oracle Support log on to be able to access it.

Comment: Hello i got the same problem from a long time, but to access the oracle solution, you need to provide a Support Identifier from where did you get it please?

Comment: @Amira you need a log on to see this.  However it describes a patch for 12.2.1.2.0.  This would have been fixed in subsequent release of .3 or .4 so can you upgrade to to latest version?

Comment: @andyfish thank you for your help :), I logged in with my Oracle occount but it requires a support identifier that i don't know from where i can get it :/

Comment: @Amira the patch id is 25729346 however the support identifier you talk about is likely to be that you need to have a support contract with Oracle.

Comment: @andyfish many thanks i'll see it with Oracle support team :)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
```

causes your remote calls in the same JVM to have local call semantics, including exception handling.

Comment: Thanks, but changing this setting does not resolve my problem.

Comment: Make sure you fully un-deploy and then re-deploy your application. WebLogic has historically not been good at noticing changes in deployment descriptors

Comment: Restarted and delete app/cleared caches but still the same error.

Comment: I believe that somewhere in your system there is some configuration that is causing this because the behaviour you are seeing is not spec compliant.

Comment: I've actually created a simple war with the 2.1 ejbs and deployed to a new domain with the same issue.